# How to cast a struct of 2 uint into a double

Tags: c

I have a struct like below:

```
struct pts_t 
{
    uint32_t lsb;
    uint32_t msb;
};
```

I would like cast that into a double.  Is it safe of directly write:

```
pts_t t; 

double timestamp = t;
```

and more complex, if the struct type is part of a C dll API, without having "packing" attribute (for all compiler) in that case I have to copy the `pts_t*`receive througth the API to pts_t instance i create to control the struct packing ?

```
void f(pts_t* t)
{ 
   pts_t myt; myt.lsb = t->lsb; myt.msb = t->msb;

   double timestamp = *(double*)(&myt.lsb);
}
```

Comment: `double timestamp = (double)(*((uint64_t*)&t));`

Comment: can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial thought would be to write the following:

```
double timestamp = *( ( double * ) &( t.lsb ) );
```

To step through this (assuming you are in a 32-bit environment):

1. You are getting the address of the identifier `t.lsb` because you need to find the memory address of the first byte in your structure. Note, you can alternatively do `&t`.
2. You are then casting that memory address to be a pointer to a double (8 bytes).
3. You are lastly dereferencing that pointer and storing all 8 bytes in the 8 byte block of memory that the identifier `timestamp` uses.

**Remark:**

1. You will need to consider little/big endianness.
2. You are assuming that both the structure and double are aligned properly (as mentioned below).
3. This is not portable, you are assuming that a double is 8 bytes.

Now, the three points in the remark blurb are a lot to worry about. It becomes a big pain when porting this code accross multiple platforms. As mentioned below, using C `unions` is a much better and correct solution that is portable.

It would be written as follows with C `unions`:

```
double timestamp = ( union { double d; struct pts_t pts; } ) { t } .d;
```

Comment: `pts_t` uses `uint32_t`, so it should work regardless of the size of a standard `int` (although the compiler is probably less likely to insert padding bits between the fields on a 32-bit than on a 64-bit environment)

Comment: @Virgile, my assumption of a 32-bit environment for my short blurb was so that I can state a double requires 8 bytes. If a double was more or less than 8 bytes then you would run into issues of accessing memory addresses you have not allocated.

Comment: This is undefined behavior (resulting in a BUS error) if the structure and double are aligned differently. Don't do that.

Comment: This code also violates aliasing rules. Using a union, as in [Jens Gustedt’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18142604/298225) is the correct way to reinterpret bytes.

Comment: You are right, implementing this using a `union` would be a guaranteed solution to this problem. I have addressed this in my post.

Comment: Since using a `union` is the correct way, why not put it at the top and remove the unnecessary and incorrect aliasing method completely? With C 1999 or later, you can reinterpret bytes through a union in a single line with `double timestamp = (union { struct pts_t p; double d; }) { t } .d;`.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you assume that your `double` are 64 bit wide, if you are looking for portable code you should be really careful with that: your structure and `double` might have different alignment constraints and your compiler may get confused because of aliasing rules. A way to avoid problems with that is to use a `union`

```
union {
 struct pts_t pts;
 double timestamp;
} x = { .pts = t };
```

and then use `x.timestamp`.

Also be careful that "composing" `double`s like that might result in strange values such as infinities that you wouldn't encounter otherwise.

Comment: @alexbuisson This is the better answer

Answer (score 3):

You have to write

```
double timestamp = *( (double*)(&t.lsb));
```

You should use something like

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) pts_t {
    ...
};
```

to make sure that your struct is packed (though I can't see why any compiler would pad something after the lsb in this case).

...

Actually depending whether your platform is big- or littleendian you might have to switch lsb and msb or do something like this:

```
double timestamp;
double* p_timestamp = &timestamp;
*((uint32_t*)p_timestamp) = t.msb;
*( ((uint32_t*)p_timestamp) + 1) = t.lsb;
```

Comment: About struct packing and if the pts_t is pass as a pointer through a C DLL API, see my edit.

Comment: This is undefined behavior (resulting in a BUS error) if the structure and double are aligned differently. Don't do that.

Comment: This code also violates aliasing rules. Using a union, as in [Jens Gustedt’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18142604/298225) is the correct way to reinterpret bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
struct pts_t 
{
    uint32_t lsb;
    uint32_t msb;
};
```

This:

```
pts_t t; 
double timestamp = t;
```

is perfectly "safe", in the sense that it won't compile so it can't do any harm. You haven't defined a type `pts_t`; you've defined a type `struct pts_t`.

This:

```
struct pts_t t;
double timestamp = t;
```

also won't compile, because you can't convert (either explicitly, with a cast, or implicitly, with an assignment) a value of a struct type to an object of numeric type.

I humbly suggest that you would have saved some time if you'd tried that before posting.

Probably the most straightforward approach is to use `memcpy()`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
/* ... */
struct pts_t t = { some_lsb_value, some_msbZ_value };
double timestamp;
assert(sizeof t == sizeof timestamp);
memcpy(&timestamp, &t, sizeof timestamp);
```

By using `memcpy()` rather than pointer casts, you avoid any risk of misaligned memory access; depending on the system, your struct might require either more or less strict alignment than a `double`.

There's also no guarantee that your struct is the same size as a `double`. The struct is almost certainly 64 bits, and `double` is *probably* 64 bits, but neither is actually guaranteed, and it doesn't hurt to make your assumptions explicit.

That leaves open the question of whether the values you've stored in `t.lsb` and `t.msb`, when taken together, make up a representation for a valid `double` value, particularly for the value you want.  The language says very little about how floating-point types are represented. In particular, endianness can and does vary across different systems. It's up to you to make sure that reinterpreting the representation in this way actually makes sense -- and your code is likely to be non-portable.